# How to fetch all tweets using tweepy stream API

Tags: python, twitter, streaming, tweepy

I am trying to fetch all tweets using tweepy. I cannot find a document to show how to fetch all tweets rather than filter data using some keywords.

I tried "stream.filter()" without parameters, but it still does not work.

Could anyone give some help?

Thanks.

Comment: You are using public or user or site stream

Comment: I am using public stream.

Comment: After reading more documents of twitter streaming API, I think this has to be achieved by firehose API. However, to use firehose API, I have to request twitter to grant permission and it seems that I need to pay for the permission.

Comment: You can't do this with the Twitter API. Try including common words (a, i, the) in your filter text to catch as many tweets as possible

Comment: Hi @LeoYao, did you figured out something to get all the tweets ? 
Thanks